# Multiple sqlite installs on same server

Tags: linux, sqlite, installation, configure

I've got a server at work on which I am basically building an apache/mysql/subversion/php/python development base.  I've found that the RPM repos the server is pointed at only have version 3.3.6-5 of sqlite, which subversion 1.6.17 chokes on, requiring at least version 3.4:

```
An appropriate version of sqlite could not be found.  We recommmend 3.6.13,
but require at least 3.4.0. Please either install a newer sqlite on this
system or get the sqlite 3.6.13 amalgamation from:
http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3.6.13.tar.gz
unpack the archive using tar/gunzip and copy sqlite3.c from the
resulting directory to:
/root/installs/subversion-1.6.17/sqlite-amalgamation/sqlite3.c
This file also ships as part of the subversion-deps distribution.
```

I managed to download and build sqlite (sqlite-autoconf-3070701.tar.gz), but now when I run sqlite3, I'm getting the error:

```
sqlite3: symbol lookup error: sqlite3: undefined symbol: sqlite3_sourceid
```

I'm sure this is because the PATH variable has the so files for both the rpm installation of sqlite (/usr), and the compiled version I installed (/usr/local).  I can't yum remove the exiting sqlite because it is tied to the installation of rpm, so what I would like to do is add whatever I need to my profile or bashrc or whatever other black magic is needed to allow some users to run the updated sqlite install, while others just default to the original install.

Other info:

```
# cat /etc/*-release
Enterprise Linux Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Carthage)
Oracle Linux Server release 5.6
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.1 (Tikanga)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Tikanga)
# uname -m
x86_64
```

Can anyone tell me what I can do to get the two copies of sqlite to play together nicely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried what the error message from subversion proposes?

> ...get the sqlite 3.6.13 amalgamation from:
>   http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3.6.13.tar.gz unpack the
>   archive using tar/gunzip and copy sqlite3.c from the resulting
>   directory to:
>   /root/installs/subversion-1.6.17/sqlite-amalgamation/sqlite3.c

Comment: To tell you the truth, I don't know much about what an "amalgamation" is.  I'd rather have the mos

Comment: amalgation means that _all_ the sqlite C code is in one file (sqlite3.c); according to the error message you would copy it to /root/installs/subversion-1.6.17/sqlite-amalgamation/ and then subversion should be able to use it.

Comment: Oops - lets try that again.  To tell you the truth, I don't know much about what an "amalgamation" is.  I'd rather have the most up to date version of sqlite working with subversion - not an API masked older version.  I guess I'll give it whirl and see where it leads.

Comment: Thanks sixfeetsix.  I'm going to do that now and let you know how it goes.  I'd still like to be able to use the new version of sqlite without having to - I guess you call this "statically linking it".  Any ideas besides the amalgamation route?

Comment: I'm guessing there is a decent chance that it would be safe to put the latest sqlite3.c file instead of the 3.6.13 version; but it's up to you... personally I'd just put the version suggested by the error message. The latest version I believe is http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3070701.zip

Comment: Well, it looks like it worked.  I added the line `--with-sqlite=/root/installs/sqlite-amalgamation-3070701/sqlite3.c ` to my configure script, and subversion happily configured and subsequently make-installed.  However, I still cannot access the newer sqlite version from the command line.  I'll leave this open another day or two to see if anyone else has any ideas about that or if I stumble across a solution.  If nothing else, I'll mark your answer as the accepted answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: @ogradyjd I know it was three years ago, but have you found a solution? Hit the same problem on a very old RedHat5  server where I cannot upgrade the software