# I upgraded Ubuntu form 10 to 12.04 and now sqlite3 does not work

Tags: sqlite, ubuntu-12.04

I have tried removing and installing it.

I did

```
    sudo apt-get remove sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

manually went in to the folders

```
    /usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib
    /lib
```

and searched "sqlite3" and deleted all of the files

then I did

```
    sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

and when I do

```
    $sqlite3
```

in the terminal I get

```
    sqlite3: symbol lookup error: sqlite3: undefined symbol: sqlite3_sourceid
```

EDIT: In python if I type import sqlite in the interpreter I get

```
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlite/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import _sqlite
    ImportError: libsqlite.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

EDIT 2: I searched for the file

```
    libsqlite.so.0
```

and found it in

```
    /opt/lampp/lib
```

and now in the python interpreter I can

```
    >>> import sqlite
    >>> sqlite.version
    '1.0.1'
    >>> import sqlite3
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named sqlite3
```

Comment: Does the error message offer a proposed solution?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365840/multiple-sqlite-installs-on-same-server

Comment: That is the entire error message.